# Get log file of a job id from travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, logfile

How can i download the log file of build from a job id and project name. I knew that there is API from travis ci.

Project name : eclipse/jetty.project
Job id : 6073028

Link to access to the log file : 
https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/jetty.project/jobs/6073028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found archive of builds of travis ci in the following link,

https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/6073028/log.txt

or

https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/6073028/log.txt

Just replace the number of your job id

Comment: This approach does not work for private builds (travis-ci.com).

Comment: if they are private, that mean that you are not allowed to have access

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Could you give a better response then ?

Comment: This answer's approach works for only public builds. Private builds are accessible to people that have access to the private builds. The comparable technique to access private builds is completely ridiculous, including typing your GitHub password into some random command-line software that Travis makes you install. I didn't get past that step yet.