# Download raw build logs from all builds on a specific branch

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

Is there an easy way to download the Travis CI build logs for all builds of a specific branch?

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644630/get-log-file-of-a-job-id-from-travis-ci), it is possible to get a specific log file. This can be used in a bash loop over job ids,

```
for JOBID in $(COMMAND-HERE)
do
  wget https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/$JOBID/log.txt
done
```

but I'm not sure how to get the job numbers associated with, for example, the `develop` branch of the repository.